# Convert formula into Java

Tags: java, math

I would like to take this formula:

[image: Formula]

and convert it into java code. I don't think that the below code is correct, because I think I am getting the wrong result.

```
return (int)(2 * a * b + Math.pow(a, 2) * (1 - 2 * b));
```

Here is the original image I am working with:
http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/4800000/Beach-beaches-4843817-1280-800.jpg

a = the invert of the image link
b = the image link

Below is what I would be expecting my output to look like (PhotoShop):

[image: Expected Result]

This is what my output actually looks like (My Application):

[image: Actual Result]

```
Invert inv = new Invert();
inv.setStage(stage);
inv.setParent(this);
BufferedImage img = inv.filter();
int[] invPixels = new int[stage.width * stage.height];
img.getRGB(0, 0, stage.width, stage.height, invPixels, 0, stage.width);
for(int i = 0; i < ImageSync.originalPixels.length; i++){
    int fg = invPixels[i];
    int bg = ImageSync.originalPixels[i];
    int color = Blends.softLight(fg, bg);
    invPixels[i] = color;
}
img = new BufferedImage(stage.width, stage.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
img.setRGB(0, 0, stage.width, stage.height, invPixels, 0, stage.width);
Preview.setImage(img);
stage.preview = Preview.getImage();
this.repaint();
```

softLight:

```
public static int softLight(int background, int foreground){
    return (2 * background * foreground) + ((background * background) * (1 - 2 * foreground));
}
```

Comment: Looks right to me.  I think if your answer is incorrect, you might be having trouble with precision.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson. Well, I don't see any precedence problem there.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you think your 'wrong result' is?

Comment: This is supposed to be a formula to calculate "Soft Light" where `a` represents the lower pixel and `b` represents the upper pixel. The only reason I think that it is wrong is because the displayed image doesn't look right.

Comment: Would be helpful if you give us an example of `a` and `b`, your expected and your actual result.

Comment: I have little understanding of exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but based on a quick glance at google results, you probably want a and b to be double (if they are not already), and should not cast to int, but rather return a double value.

Comment: @jlordo I updated the main question.

Comment: thanks, but I think we had a small misunderstanding :) I was talking about the formula, and something like this from you: `a=10;` `b=20;` I expect the formula to evaluate to `37` but the result is `42`.

Comment: The image, to me anyway, isn't really helpful.  What do you mean by "the image link" and "the invert of the image link".  That doesn't make sense to me.  One would assume a and b are numbers.

Comment: Okay maybe the source code at the bottom is a little more helpful?

Comment: Are you sure you must do pixel by pixel calculations ? Are not images treated with matrix ?

Comment: Okay, so they are numeric color representations.  Not sure this equation is what your looking for, just doing a test calculation: (2* 0x111111 * 0xEEEEEE + 0x111111 * 0x111111 + (1 - 2 * 0xEEEEEE) ) = (approx) 0x20FEDA954E40 .  Clearly not a valid result.  Probably being truncated somewhere down the line, and giving you pretty random results.  To me that looks like an equation meant to handle values between 0 and 1, at a glance.

Comment: are you sure the picture is RGB and not ARGB or another format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try trivial calculation:

```
return (2 * a * b ) + (a * a * (1 - 2 * b));
```

Answer (score 2):

the code is correct. but you typecast the result to int which can alter the result. id recommend using double or float.

and important: make sure a & b are also float or double.

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = (2*a*b)+((a*a)*(1-(2*b)));
```

As @shippy said make sure that `a` and `b` are `int`.